# Label the extreme values in each group in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a ggplot combination of geom_violin and geom_point, I would like to label the extreme values of each group. However, this should be strictly group-based.
My solution so far just gives me the extreme values of every group and labels each of them in every group. As in the real data I have 10 groups and 3 extremes this makes the graph unreadable.

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(group = c('XvsHD', 'XvsHD', 'XvsHD', 'XvsHD', 'YvsHD', 'YvsHD', 'YvsHD', 'YvsHD', 'ZvsHD', 'ZvsHD', 'ZvsHD', 'ZvsHD'),
protein = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'R'),
logFC = c(-1, 2 , 4, 5, 2, 6, -3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2))

extremes <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% slice_max(order_by = logFC, n = 2, preserve = T)%>% pull(protein)
```

## Plots

```
   df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= group, y = logFC)) +
    geom_violin() +   
    geom_point() 

    df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= group, y = logFC)) +
    geom_violin() +   
    geom_point() +
    geom_label_repel(aes(label= ifelse(protein %in% extremes, as.character(protein), NA),hjust=0, vjust=0))
```

The goal is to have a plot, where the 2 most extreme values of each group are labeled with the 'protein' tag. Really cool would be if this works for the extremely low as well as for the high values/group.

Thank you very much!

Sebastian

Comment: geom_label_repel(aes(label= ifelse(abs(logFC) > 3, as.character(protein), NA),hjust=0, vjust=0)) does not work, because the max Fc levels per group differ a lot. Some groups have a max(Fc) of just 1 while others have >6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `label` column which has `protein` value only if it is minimum or maximum `logFC` value in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(logFC %in% range(logFC), protein, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= group, y = logFC, label = label)) +
  geom_violin() +   
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

[image]

---

To label top and bottom `n` values you can use `dense_rank` function.

```
n <- 2

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(min_rank = dense_rank(logFC), 
         max_rank = dense_rank(-logFC)) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(min_rank <= n | max_rank <= n, protein, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= group, y = logFC, label = label)) +
  geom_violin() +   
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! An issue is, that this solution labels only the top1 max and min points of each group. Is there a way to extend this to the top2/3/5 of max and min? After a quick check of the range function, there seems to be no option for it?

Comment: In that case we can use `dense_rank` function to assign ranks. See updated answer. If you want different to label different top and bottom values you need to define `n` and `m`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different solution from Ronak Shah in that it uses `rank` to find the two most extreme values (defined as difference from the mean). It is not necessary that one extreme is high and one low: both extreme values could be high, or both low.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    logFC_demean = scale(logFC, scale = FALSE),
    label = ifelse(rank(-abs(logFC_demean), ) <= 2, protein, "")) 


ggplot(df, aes(x= group, y = logFC, label = label)) +
  geom_violin() +   
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! The issue with this solution is that, in some groups, the positive Fc levels are much higher than the negative ones. This leads to some groups having labels at 4 extreme pos values while others have 2 pos and 2 neg (or 1 pos and 3 neg)... any way this could be changed so its always the top2/3/5?

Comment: if you always want the top, just take out the `abs`. If you want top and bottom 2, you will need something like `rank(-logFC_demean) <= 2 | rank(logFC_demean) <= 2`. This is equivalent to the solution Ronak has now posted